# JSF 2.0: Why does a JSF bean get created when it's used in a component that is not rendered?

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, javabeans

Let's have an extremely simple composite component:

```
<cc:implementation>
    #{testBean.someField}
</cc:implementation>
```

Bean for it:

```
public class TestBean {

    private boolean someField = false;
    public boolean getSomeField() { return someField; }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("PostConstruct");
    }

}
```

Then call it as usual but don't show it:

```
<codeEditor:test rendered="#{false}" />
```

What happens is that the component is never rendered and the bean is never initiated as one would suppose.

However, if we change the component as:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.someField}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

What happens is that the component still never gets rendered (because the `rendered` attribute is `false`), however, the bean does get instantiated. This happens always when we use a bean property inside some native JSF component (`h:panelGroup`, `h:inputHidden`, whatever).

Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The components (and all of the bound beans) get created during view build time. The rendered attribute is only evaluated during view render time. It has always worked that way in JSF.

If the bean is doing some expensive job during construction, then I'd suggest to let that expensive job depend on the some condition which you then reuse in the rendered attribute.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I knew it's something fundamental but not exactly what. Don't you feel bad for creating components and beans when they are not even used?

Comment: So I guess the only way around this is to use UIComponents instead of composite components :/ Please correct me, if wrong.

Comment: Just tried a hack around this: use an ui:repeat with 0-1 elements dependending on whether you want the contents to be initialized or not. I created a method in the backing to return an empty list when the contents should not be created and to return a single dummy element (whatever) inside a list when the content is supposed to be created and rendered. It bloats the component tree a bit, but should work in basic cases at least.